# Symfony2 RestBundle unable to get POST param

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I extends a FOSRestController and try to receive POST requests, but I'm unable to get the param, and all the requests to that API endpoint results in error:

```
Controller MapmsisdnController::postMapmsisdnAction() requires that you provide a value for the $deviceId argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one). (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my class and the annotation

```
class MapmsisdnController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * Map a deviceid to msisdn
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  resource = true,
     *  description = "Map an msisdn for a single deviceid",
     *  statusCodes = {
     *      200 = "Returned when successful",
     *      500 = "Internal Server Error"
     *  }
     * )
     * @Post("/mapmsisdn")
     * @param type $deviceId
     * @param type $msisdn
     */
    public function postMapmsisdnAction($deviceId, $msisdn)
    {
        $test = true;
        if ( $test ) {
            $result = array(
                "code" => 200,
                "message" => "ok",
                "deviceId" => $deviceId,
                "msisdn" => $msisdn
            );
            $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
            $ret = $serializer->serialize($result, 'json');
            return new Response($ret);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the annotation, you should specify @Post, and specify your params one by one using @RequestParam like this:

```
@Post("/mapmsisdn")
@RequestParam(name="deviceId", requirements="\d+", default="", description="Device ID.")
@RequestParam(name="msisdn", requirements="\d+", default="", description="MSISDN.")
```

then you can retrieve the parameters like this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->get('deviceId');
$request->get('msisdn');
```

@RequestParam is of this:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RequestParam;
```